# Why do the default Raku if/while/loop/when blocks all have the same identity value (.WHICH)?

Tags: raku, routines

Except for the block where I declared a signature, all of the blocks have the same identity value, and claim to be declared on line 1 regardless of where they occur. Could anyone shed some light as to why this is the case?

```
say ｢Let's look at some blocks…｣;

if True {
  &?BLOCK.say;
}

while True {
  &?BLOCK.say;
  last;
}

loop {
  &?BLOCK.say;
  last;
}

if True -> | {
  ｢I'm different!｣.say;
  &?BLOCK.say;
}

when ?True {
  &?BLOCK.say;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: `.say` does **NOT** give you the identity value, because that calls the `.gist` method on the given expression.  For the identity value, you need to call the `.WHICH` method.  Fortunately, the `Block.gist` method *does* include the identity value in its stringification.  But that is *not* guaranteed to be the case for all objects.

What you see there, is the static optimizer at work: because nothing is happening inside the block, it can be discarded.  In the one case where it is different (where you specified an alternate signature), it *is* different.  If you run this script with `--optimize=0` or `--optimize=1`, then all blocks *will* have different identity values.

I guess you could call it an issue that mentioning `&?BLOCK` does not inhibit the static optimizer from flattening the scope.  On the other hand, you could also call this a case of DIHWIDT (Doctor, It Hurts When I Do This).  So don't do that then  :-)

UPDATE: it is the different signature that made the difference.  Daniel Mita++

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I'm not sure I follow for the 2nd paragraph. The creation of the string is not what makes a difference, it's the signature for the block that does (it has the same identity value if I remove the signature but keep the string).